# What is the purpose of sort_index of a Dataclass in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses, data-class

I am learning about Dataclasses but I am confused on the purpose of sort_index and how it actually works.

I can't seem to find any valuable information on it. The official Python documentation doesn't mention it, which is mind boggling.

Here is an example:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Person:
    sort_index: int = field(init=False, repr=False)
    name: str
    age: int
    weight: int = 190
 
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.sort_index = self.weight
```

So, what is the purpose of sort_index? What is it used for? When do I use it?

Thanks again for taking the time to answer my question. I am new to Python.

Comment: The official Python documentation doesn't mention it for the same reason as it doesn't mention `name`, `age` or `weight`. It is a user-defined field. You need to look in the documentation for the class `Person`, not in the documentation for `dataclass`.

Answer (score 8):

**Setting a `sort_index` attribute (or indeed, *any* identifier—the name is irrelevant) in the `__post_init__` method appears to be the value on which comparisons are performed.**

There is an implicit setting of the comparison methods (`__lt__`, `__gt__`, etc--read about dunder methods if unfamiliar), using the attributes provided in the `__post_init__` method first, and if required, the remaining attributes for resolution.

*Class constructor*

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(order=True)
class Person:
    sort_index: int = field(init=False)
    age: int
      
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.sort_index = self.age
```

**first example**—attribute `age` is equal:

```py
>>> p1 = Person(age=10)
>>> p2 = Person(age=10)
>>> p1 == p2
True
```

**Second example**—`age` is greater:

```py
>>> p1 = Person(age=10)
>>> p2 = Person(age=20)
>>> p2 > p1
True
```

**More complex example**:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(order=True)
class Person:
    foo: int = field(init=False, repr=False)
    bar: int = field(init=False, repr=False)
    name: str
    age: int
    weight: int = 190
    
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.foo = self.weight
        self.bar = self.age
        
>>> p1 = Person('p1', 10)
>>> p2 = Person('p1', 11)
>>> p2 > p2
True
```

**Reason**
`foo` (`weight`) is equal for both instances, so comparison is done on `bar` (`age`)

**Conclusion**
The comparisons can be arbitrarily complex, and identifiers are not important.

I highly recommend this [video on dataclasses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRVVyl9uaZc), by ArjanCodes.
Apart from the video, here's a github link to [example dataclass code](https://github.com/ArjanCodes/2021-dataclasses/blob/main/dataclasses-after.py) (from the same video).

Hope this helped—I just learned about dataclasses myself.

Comment: the video link just links to this page

Comment: Works fine for me, you might need to see what's going wrong for you.  

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRVVyl9uaZc)

Comment: Thank you for this good explanation. What may not be entirely clear is that `sort_index` or `foo` or `bar` must come first in list of fields for the dataclass... their order matters. Putting them last in the list of fields makes them last. Wanted to point that out.

Comment: Great answer to OPs question, but is this (in my opinion very obfuscated) behavior documented anywhere in the python docs? Is this expected to change?
I could not find anything of this behavior mentioned in the official python docs?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've found the simple truth about that.

First, 'sort_index' or whatever you want to call this attribute, in not usefull unless you need to sort the class depending on an attribute defined after the init is done (then defined in the post_init).

All the tricky behaviour comes from how @dataclasse(order=True) works.
It is not intended to make direct comparisons like var1 > var2, but it is used to sort your objects, if, lets say you store them into an iterable that you can sort.
And this sorting is done like that (objects must be instances from the same class of course):

- compare the first attribute to sort the objects
- in case of equality -> compare with the second attribute, etc...

So, the order the attributes are wrote matters. And that is why one may use a 'sort_index' simply to put this attribute in the first place even though it is not defined in the init, but after the init.

(I've found a good explanation in this [video](https://www.google.com/search?q=dataclasse%20order%20demo&oq=dataclasse%20order%20demo&aqs=chrome..69i57.5816j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:087eaaeb,vid:myENiF_Zw7Q))

```py
@dataclass(order=True)
class Person:
    sort_index: int = field(init=False) # <- not defined yet
    age: int
    name: str
      
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.sort_index = self.age  # <- definition's here

# if you try this:
print(person_1 == person_2)

# and get 'True', it means that all the values of the attributes of person_1 
# and person_2 are strictly the same, not only 'sort_index'
```

In this example, the first sorting attribute is sort_index which is also the age, it is not a very good example. A better attribute could be an autogenerated id given after the init of the object, but even then, it would be easier to do:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Person:
    id: int = field(init=False, default_factory=get_an_id_function)
    age: int
    name: str

# Where get_an_id_function is a function that returns an id
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use the `compare=False` attribute in `dataclasses.field` to exclude a certain field from the ordering methods. For example:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(order=True)
class Entry:
    nr: list[int, int] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=lambda: [0, 0])
    p: int = dataclasses.field(default_factory=int, compare=False)
```

Only the field `nr` is used by the generated equality and comparison methods (`__eq__()`, `__gt__()`, et al.).